# How can I filter paginated results based on the value of associated models? (CakePHP 2.x)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I have 3 models in cakephp

1. properties

```
property id   name    area    sub area
1             name    1       india   --
2             name    2       india   --
3             name    3       uk    --
4             name    4       pakistan  --
```

2. portals

```
portals_id  portal name
1           google xml
2           zameen.com
3           buy property
4           rent property
```

3. property_portals

```
property_portals_id    portal_id    property_id
1                      1            1            
2                      1            1
3                      2            2 
4                      2            2 
5                      2            3
6                      1            4 
7                      1            1
```

I have a grid system which search properties on different attributes.
Now i want to search only those properties which will advertise on specific portal.

I am using pagination.

```
$this->set('properties', $this->Paginator->paginate('Property'));
```

Comment: i am searching on properties and now i want to check how many properties are advertised on a specific portal. so my search query contains "properties" and "properties_portals" models

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try the [CakeDC Search plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search). You can configure almost any type of search (no matter how complex), and it's compatible with Pagination.

The [first example in the docs](https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Examples.md) includes a sample on how to configure `$filterArgs` to perform a HABTM search.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have declared a HABTM relationship in your models like so:

```
class Property extends AppModel {

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Portal' => array(
        'className' => 'Portal',
        'joinTable' => 'property_portals',
        'foreignKey' => 'portal_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'property_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

And vice versa for your Portal Model

Then you should be able set the query parameters for your pagination like this:

```
$this->Property->Portal->paginate('Post', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Portal.id' => $idOfPortalYouWantToSearch
    ), 'order' => array(
        'COUNT(property_portals_id )'
    )
));
```

And then query with:

```
$this->set('properties', $this->Paginator->paginate('Property'));
```

Did not test it but it should work.